# What ships appear in the DS9 intro?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

For the fourth season of *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, the theme song and intro were updated. In it, various ships are seen flying around or docking in the station. My question is simple

**What ship models are visible in the intro? I have personally seen runabouts and a *Galaxy*-class ship.**

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/DS9_Season_4

Comment: For the record it's not a Galaxy class, it's a Nebula class ship in the intro,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We see (in order)

- Three Danube-class 'Runabout' vessels. These are (presumably) the **[USS Orinoco](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Orinoco), [USS Rio Grande](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Rio_Grande) and the [USS Rubicon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Rubicon)**

  [image]
- We see a large Nebula Class vessel docked at the upper pylon. This is the **[USS Leeds](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Leeds)**

  [image]
- A **[Work Bee](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cargo_management_unit)** (and some workers)

  [image]
- **A large Freighter**. This hasn't been identified, but most fans seem to agree that it's [Morn's ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Morn%27s_cargo_ship)

  [image]
- A generic **[Janitza-class](https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/cardguide/images/2/2a/Assaultvessel_2E.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20121230093426) [Bajoran Starship](https://web.archive.org/web/20090606200449/http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/items/1778-0498)**

  [image]
- The **[USS Defiant](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(2370))**

  [image]